# Dump vim screen into a file

Tags: vim

I need to dump whatever is seen on the vim screen as it is, with colors and everything. Is there a way do to id. I am hoping that ncurses uses the same escape sequence for colors as bash. So when I'll do cat on the file that I've dumped the screen to, I should get the same output as the vim file.

I want to use it in the scenario when I am doing a side by side colorful diff of files and need to print them.

If anyone knows of any other side-by-side colorful diff programs, please feel free to mention in the comments (not answers because I am hoping that this question will be answered so that it can be used by others).

---

Thanks for TOhtml answer, but how do I do it if I'm in diff mode? I want both the side by side diffs to appear.

Comment: `mgdiff` is a motif based graphical frontend for diff. It's available in Debian packages e.g. (you didn't tell your OS).

Answer (score 2):

try `:TOhtml`, see also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Pasting_code_with_syntax_coloring_in_emails

Comment: It's actually :TOhtml.

Comment: @ggustafsson: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
:TOhtml
```

(not `:ToHTML` as akira told you before).